# XNA Bullet Hitbox wont follow the sprite thus causing problems with collision

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, xna, monogame

Im making a spaceinvaderisch kinda game in XNA/Monogame
Everything was going great until I encountered this problem.
Ive been trying to fix the bullet hitboxes for days but to no succes.
My problem lies in the fact that the hitbox doesnt move with the bullet itself.
The Collision detection is in the Game1 class. The actual movement in Bullets class and the trigger to shoot is in the Tank class. The Bullet is also inherited to Sprite.cs which gives it a hitbox.

Could anyone help me out. I really just want to finish what ive started before I start working on something else.

Help is Dearly Appreciated.

Game1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace IsisInvaders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Tank Tank;
        Isis Isis1;
        Isis Isis2;
        Isis Isis3;
        Isis Isis4;
        Isis Isis5;
    Isis Isis6;
    Isis Isis7;
    Isis Isis8;
    Isis Isis9;
    Isis Isis10;
    Isis Isis11;
    Bullets Bullets;
    private Song BgMusic;

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;

    enum GameState
    {
        MainMenu,
        Playing,
    }
    GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;

    Button btnPlay;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        //Bullet = new Bullets(Tank.position);
        Tank = new Tank(new Vector2 (375,425));
        Isis1 = new Isis(new Vector2(30, 0));
        Isis2 = new Isis(new Vector2(70, 0));
        Isis3 = new Isis(new Vector2(110, 0));
        Isis4 = new Isis(new Vector2(150, 0));
        Isis5 = new Isis(new Vector2(190, 0));
        Isis6 = new Isis(new Vector2(230, 0));
        Isis7 = new Isis(new Vector2(270, 0));
        Isis8 = new Isis(new Vector2(310, 0));
        Isis9 = new Isis(new Vector2(350, 0));
        Isis10 = new Isis(new Vector2(390, 0));
        Isis11 = new Isis(new Vector2(430, 0));
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        btnPlay = new Button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Start"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        IsMouseVisible = true;


        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        btnPlay.setPosition(new Vector2(350, 300));
        BgMusic = Content.Load<Song>("Music");
        Tank.LoadContent(this.Content, "Tank");
        Isis1.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis2.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis3.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis4.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis5.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis6.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis7.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis8.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis9.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis10.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Isis11.LoadContent(this.Content, "Isis");
        Sounds.BgMusic(BgMusic);
        screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// game-specific content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here


        //Bullet.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);

        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                if (btnPlay.isClicked == true)
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
                }
                btnPlay.Update(mouse);
                break;
            case GameState.Playing:
                Isis1.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis2.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis3.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis4.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis5.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis6.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis7.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis8.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis9.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis10.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Isis11.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);
                Tank.Update(screenWidth, screenHeight, gameTime);                   
                break;
        }
        //Collision
        foreach (Bullets item in Tank.bullets)
        {
            if (item.Bullethitbox.Intersects(Isis1.Box))
            {
                Isis1.LoadContent(this.Content, "DeadIsis");           
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.SandyBrown);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.White);
                btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
                break;
            case GameState.Playing:
                Tank.Draw(spriteBatch);           
                Isis1.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis2.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis3.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis4.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis5.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis6.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis7.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis8.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis9.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis10.Draw(spriteBatch);
                Isis11.Draw(spriteBatch);
                break;
        }
        //Bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Bullets.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace IsisInvaders
{
class Bullets : Sprite
{
    private Vector2 Position;

    public Bullets(Vector2 Position) : base(Position)
    {
        this.Position = Position;

    }

    public override void Update(int screenWidth, int Screenheight, GameTime gametime)
    {
        int Pos = (int)Position.Y;
        Pos -= 10;
        Position.Y = Pos;


    }
    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager Contentman, string Spritename)
    {
        base.LoadContent(Contentman, Spritename);
        spritetext = Contentman.Load<Texture2D>("Bullet");
        //this.Box = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, spritetext.Width, spritetext.Height);
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(spritetext, Position, Color.White);
    }

    public Texture2D Bulletsprite { get { return this.spritetext; } }
    public Vector2 Bulletposition { get { return this.Position; } set { this.Position = value; } }

    public Rectangle Bullethitbox { get { return this.Box; } set { this.Box = value; } }
}
 }
```

Tank.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace IsisInvaders
{

class Tank : Sprite
{
    private Vector2 P;
    private KeyboardState KBS = Keyboard.GetState();
    private float bulletspeed = -400f;
    public List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
    private float reload = 0;
    Bullets Bullet;
    ContentManager Content;
    public Tank(Vector2 Position) : base(Position)
    {

    }

    public override void Update(int screenWidth, int Screenheight, GameTime gametime)
    {
        KBS = Keyboard.GetState();
        P = this.position;
        if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            P.X += 8;
            this.position = P;
        }
        if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            P.X -= 8;
            this.position = P;
        }
        reload += (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (reload >= 500 && KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            Bullets b = new Bullets(position);
            b.LoadContent(Content, "Bullet");
            bullets.Add(b);                
            reload = 0;
        }
        foreach (Bullets item in bullets)
        {
            //item.Bullethitbox = new Rectangle((int)item.Bulletposition.X, (int)item.Bulletposition.Y, item.Bulletsprite.Width, item.Bulletsprite.Height);
            item.Update(screenWidth, Screenheight, gametime);
        }
        //for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    float y = bullets[i].position.Y;
        //    y += bulletspeed * (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        //    bullets[i] = new Bullets(new Vector2(bullets[i].position.X, y));
        //}
    }

    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager Contentman, string Spritename)
    {
        base.LoadContent(Contentman, Spritename);
        this.Content = Contentman;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(spritetext, position, Color.White);
        foreach (Bullets b in bullets)
        {             
            b.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        //for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        //{
        //   spriteBatch.Draw(Bullet.Bulletsprite, position, Color.White);
        //}
    }

}
}
```

Isis.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace IsisInvaders
{
class Isis : Sprite
{
    private Vector2 P;
    public Isis(Vector2 Position) : base (Position)
    {
        P = Position;
    }

    public override void Update(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, GameTime gametime)
    {
        //P.Y += (float)0.11;
        this.position = P;
        this.Box = new Rectangle((int)P.X, (int)P.Y, spritetext.Width, spritetext.Height);
    }
}
}
```

Sprite.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace IsisInvaders
{    
class Sprite
{
    private Texture2D SpriteTexture;
    private Rectangle Hitbox;
    private Vector2 Position;

    public Sprite(Vector2 Position)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
    }

    public virtual void Update(int screenWidth, int Screenheight, GameTime gametime)
    {

    }

    public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager Contentman, string Spritename)
    {
        SpriteTexture = (Contentman.Load<Texture2D>(Spritename));
    }

    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteTexture, Position, Color.White);
    }

    public Texture2D spritetext { get { return this.SpriteTexture; } set { this.SpriteTexture = value; } }
    public Vector2 position { get { return this.Position; } set { this.Position = value; } }
    public Rectangle Box { get { return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, SpriteTexture.Width, SpriteTexture.Height); } set { this.Hitbox = value; } }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Bullets class you got a local variable called Position which will be modified in Bullets.Update(GameTime) but your hitbox refers to the Position vector in your Sprite class. Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't actually realize this, I'm looking into it Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it thanks to this tip! The Sprite.cs Box wasn't being edited.